# Why doesn't my object display when I call it?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var section = [];
var name = [];
var gender = [];
var age = [];
var favsub = [];
var studRec = { section, name, gender, age, favsub };

function saveButton() {
  section.push = document.getElementById("section").value;
  name.push = document.getElementById("name").value;
  gender.push = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  age.push = document.getElementById("age").value;
  favsub.push = document.getElementsByClassName("favsub");
  document.getElementById("saveStud").reset();
  window.alert(studyRec);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="saveStud" method="POST">
    <center>
      <p>Section</p>
      <select id="section" autofocus required>
        <option value="0">select</option>
        <option value="truth">truth</option>
        <option value="faith">faith</option>
        <option value="honesty">honesty</option>
        <option value="charity">charity</option>
        <option value="obedience">obedience</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <p>Student Name</p><input id="name" type="text" required><br>
      <p>Gender</p>
      <select id="gender">
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <p>Age</p><input id="age" type="number" required><br>
      
      <p>Favorite Subjects</p><input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
      <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
      <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>

      <button type="button" onclick="saveButton()">save</button>
      <button type="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
    </center>
  </form>
</body>
```

The purpose of the code is to get the information from the form then when you press save the values will be put in their separate arrays which are in an object, and the values on the form will reset. To test if the function works I tried to display it using document.write but when I do press the save button, it just resets but doesn't display

Comment: When a form submits, it loads the page specified by action ... which is the current page if no action is specified ... try `onclick="saveButton(); return false;"`

Comment: array push() is a function. An array for each value is not practical either

Comment: `push` is a function. Try `secion.push(document.getElementById("section").value)`. Also you'll probably want to use `console.log(studyRec)` for debugging instead of `window.alert`

Comment: For your alert test, you have a wrong variable... what is `studyRec`? Don't you mean `studRec`?

Comment: Post deleted... so everyone's time into this also obliterated.

Answer (score 0):

`section.push`,`name.push` and so on is wrong syntax. Apparently it mean if section and name is a object then `section.push` or so will create key in that object, but here they are not object.

Also `var studRec= {section, name, gender,age,favsub};` does not make any sense unless you are looking for object destructing and this object syntax is wrong.

You can just add keys to `studRec`  inside `saveButton` function & there is a typo at `window.alert(studyRec);`

`document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")` will gives a collection and you need to get the index to retrieve value from it.Also if you want to alert `alert(studRec)` you will only see `object object`

```js
var section = [];
var name = [];
var gender = [];
var age = [];
var favsub = [];
var studRec = {

};

function saveButton() {
  studRec.section = document.getElementById("section").value;
  studRec.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  studRec.gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  studRec.age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  studRec.favsub = document.getElementsByClassName("favsub");
  document.getElementById("saveStud").reset();
  alert(studRec);
}
```

```html
<form id="saveStud" method="POST">
  <center>
    <p>Section</p>
    <select id="section" autofocus required>
      <option value="0">select</option>
      <option value="truth">truth</option>
      <option value="faith">faith</option>
      <option value="honesty">honesty</option>
      <option value="charity">charity</option>
      <option value="obedience">obedience</option>
      <option value="chastity">chastity</option>
      <option value="generosity">generosity</option>
      <option value="humility">humility</option>
    </select><br>
    <p>Student Name</p><input id="name" type="text" required><br>
    <p>Gender</p>
    <select id="gender">
      <option value="M">Male</option>
      <option value="F">Female</option>
    </select><br>
    <p>Age</p><input id="age" type="number" required><br>
    <p>Favorite Subjects</p><input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
    <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
    <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="saveButton()">save</button>
    <button type="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
  </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add all the items to the object and then send it.
- If you're getting the element by class name then you need to iterate over by length and then get the value.
- Check the below code.
- I've included the examples if you're pushing into an array or if you want to assign a value to an object also. Try understanding the code first.

```js
var section = [];
                var name = [];
                var gender = [];
                var age = [];
                var favsub = [];
                var studyRec= {section, name, gender,age,favsub};
                function saveButton(){

                    studyRec.section=document.getElementById("section").value;
                    studyRec.name=document.getElementById("name").value;
                    studyRec.gender=document.getElementById("gender").value;
                    studyRec.age =document.getElementById("age").value;
                    studyRec.favsub.push(document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[0].value);
                    studyRec.favsub.push(document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[1].value);
                    studyRec.favsub.push(document.getElementsByClassName("favsub")[2].value);
                    document.getElementById("saveStud").reset();
                   console.log(studyRec);
                }
```

```html
<form id="saveStud" method="POST">
                <center>
                <p>Section</p><select id="section" autofocus required>
                    <option value="0">select</option>
                    <option value="truth">truth</option>
                    <option value="faith">faith</option>
                    <option value="honesty">honesty</option>
                    <option value="charity">charity</option>
                    <option value="obedience">obedience</option>
                    <option value="chastity">chastity</option>
                    <option value="generosity">generosity</option>
                    <option value="humility">humility</option>          
                </select><br>
                <p>Student Name</p><input id="name" type="text" required><br>
                <p>Gender</p><select id="gender">
                    <option value="M">Male</option>
                    <option value="F">Female</option>           
                </select><br>
                <p>Age</p><input id="age" type="number" required><br>
                <p>Favorite Subjects</p><input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
                <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>
                <input class="favsub" type="text" required><br>

                <button type = "button" onclick="saveButton()">save</button>
                <button type="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
                </center>
            </form>
```